Autosys job failed to start Elasticsearch
I have an Elasticsearch autosys job.  The Elasticsearch instance is running on the VM server. When we start Elasticsearch manually using the script, it works properly.
However, when we attempt to start the process through Autosys, it runs for a few minutes and then stops automatically, with errors being recorded in the logs folder.
Elasticsearch version: 7.17


ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [2] lines before starting Elasticsearch. 

bootstrap check failure [1] of [2]: 
max file descriptors (4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]

bootstrap check failure [2] of [2]: 
memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally check the logs at /var/log/elasticsearch/elastic-dev.log

uncaught exception in thread (process reaper (pid 23839)]

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")

at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission (AccessControlContext.java:485)


I have tried to change the elasticsearch.yml file it's not work
